# React Native Map marker

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am trying to remove standard marker (red one) from map. I have to use custom marker. Any suggestion ?

[image]

```
<Marker coordinate={data}>
  <Text style={{paddingLeft: 20, marginLeft: 60, color: 'red'}}>
    <UserAvatarContainer
      avatarUrl={Util.BackendImageBaseUrl + this.props.navigation.state.params.selectedDoctorAvatar}
    />
    {data.selectedDoctor + ' ' + data.selectedDoctorLastName}
  </Text>
</Marker>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps) you can use `image` prop to use a custom image in your marker, check [marker doc](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/marker.md)